# HttpWebRequest sends 1 cookie instead of 2

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

My program is supposed to log in to a site. To log in there you should make a request to the main page and get cookies, then you should login (http://site.com/auth/login). When I make a request to the main page and get the cookies, everything is OK, there are two cookies in the cookie container, but when I log in, there's only one cookie. Here goes the code:

```
    public CookieContainer GetCookies()
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://site.com/");
        httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "ru");
        httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; WebMoney Advisor; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0E; MALC)";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
        httpWebRequest.Timeout = 30000;
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        foreach (Cookie c in response.Cookies)
        {
            cookieContainer.Add(c);
        }
        return cookieContainer;
    }
    public bool Login(string Email, string Password, CookieContainer Cookies)
    {
        string s = "handle=" + Email + "&password=" + Password;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://site.com/auth/login");
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*";
        httpWebRequest.Referer = "http://www.lockerz.com/";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "ru-RU");
        httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; WebMoney Advisor; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0E; MALC)";
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = Cookies;
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = (long)bytes.Length;
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Pragma, "no-cache");
        httpWebRequest.Timeout = 30000;
        httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string document = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        if (document.IndexOf("Sign Out") > 1)
        {
            httpWebResponse.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            httpWebResponse.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

What's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't clear how you use `GetCookies`, but it is possible that the second response only return one cookie - do you use the same `CookieContainer` between request, or do you re-create it?

Comment: I use it like `CookieContainer cookies = GetCookies(); if(!Login(email, password, cookies)){<...>}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the httpWebRequest object theres a CookieCollection. If you dig into the variables you will find that one of the cookies is set to a different different domain than the one you're sending in your URI.  You will need to manipulate this cookie by modifying the domain to match the URI.

Hope that solves it.